# Unable to insert data php mysql - integer

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to insert integer data from insert statement.

```
$value = $_POST[from]; 
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO trip(tripid,from)VALUES(NULL, $value)");
```

Here from is integer value, but i am getting syntax error as :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;`check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`'from)VALUES(NULL, 1)'` at line 1.

Comment: `from` is a reserved keyword try: `INSERT INTO trip(tripid,``from``) VALUES (NULL, $value)`

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from is Reserved Words in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO trip(tripid,`from`)VALUES(NULL, $value)");
```

Comment: thanks so much for help, question answered.. thanks again.. :-)